No module named 'ppaquette_gym_doom'
i use spyder
i tried to install ppaquette_gym_doom but failed
i tried to install doom-py and failed
Failed building wheel for doom-py
this is error secntence but i can't understand what it means
i also tried below
import gym
import gym_pull
gym_pull.pull('github.com/ppaquette/gym-doom')        # Only required once, envs will be loaded with import gym_pull afterwards
env = gym.make('ppaquette/DoomBasic-v0')

but alse error happen
cannot import name 'load_results'
installing ppaquette_gym_doom and doom-py
upgrade wheel and pip
i tried to install ppaquette_gym_doom but failed
i tried to install doom-py and failed
Failed building wheel for doom-py
this is error secntence but i can't understand what it means
i also tried below
import gym
import gym_pull
gym_pull.pull('github.com/ppaquette/gym-doom')        # Only required once, envs will be loaded with import gym_pull afterwards
env = gym.make('ppaquette/DoomBasic-v0')

but alse error happen
cannot import name 'load_results'
installing ppaquette_gym_doom and doom-py
upgrade wheel and pip

You need to run environment
Snippet:
import gym
import ppaquette_gym_doom #<== Add module
env = gym.make('ppaquette/DoomBasic-v0')

